# How can i move a button in a UINavigation bar to the right

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

im trying to move the right button in my navigation bar to the right to align it with buttons on a table view here is what is currently looks like [image: looks like]

i made a button like this:

```
let allButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    allButton.layer.borderColor = Constants.AppColor.cgColor
    allButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    allButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    allButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectAllContacts), for: .touchUpInside)
    allButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

and im adding it to my nav bar like this:

```
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: allButton), importButton]
```

I have tried adding image insets, content insets and it doesn't work.

Any idea on what else i can try?

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Menu >",
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector( rightNavTap )
)

Comment: i don't think this would solve my issue, i just need to move my button to the right by a few pixels

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding

```
    let negativeSpacer:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = -10
```

and appending that to my array of buttons

```
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, UIBarButtonItem(customView: allButton), importButton]
```

If anyone finds a better solution let me know.